# How to sync a book that was manually added to kindle reader?

Tags: sync, kindle

I manually added a book to my kindle by connecting to a computer and adding the book file.  I read most of the book and made highlights then the physical kindle broke, so I'd like to sync the book so I can retain my highlights, however the book does not get synced to anywhere else.

How can I retrieve my highlights or sync the book to do so?

Answer (score -1):

Plug in the computer. In the Kindle disk you will find documents folder. Find the file named My Clippings.txt
It's the collection of your highlights.

Learn the details of sync Kindle
https://www.epubor.com/sync-kindle-furthest-page-read-on-computers-and-ios-android-devices.html

Comment: You should provide the "details" in your answer.  The community shouldn't have to go anywhere except your answer to get the information that answers this question.